# Autofac Property Injection in already registered service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autofac

I'm using Autofac to DI and MVVM. I have a global service registered as such:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyGlobalService>().As<IGlobalService>().SingleInstance();
```

I'm also using [Autofac.Extras.NLog](https://github.com/ziyasal/Autofac.Extras.NLog) implementation for obvious logging purposes:

```
builder.RegisterModule<NLogModule>();
```

this way I can get the instance of that service and logger in any of my ViewModels:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.ViewModels
{
    class MyViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        readonly IGlobalService _globalService;
        readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyViewModel (IGlobalService globalService, ILogger logger)
        {
            _globalService = globalService;
            _logger = logger;

}}}(...)
```

It works great.
Now I *also* want logging support inside MyGlobalService. But this time, I would like to use Property Injection, instead of Constructor Injection.

Question is: should I register such a rule differently?

Example usage:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.GlobalServices
{
    class MyGlobalService : IGlobalService
    {
        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

        public MyGlobalService ()
        {               
            Logger.Debug("My Service Starting...") 
            // no DI happening, getting exception because "Logger" is null

}}}(...)
```

Edit: Answered below.

Comment: Your code looks right. Could you include the stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand thank you for your time. i've edited my question since I wanted to property inject. Normal constructor injection is working fine!

Comment: `[External Code]` is the interesting part :) Could you right click on it and "show External Code" then edit the post :)

Comment: @CyrilDurand sorry I just realized i could do that, d'uh! edited again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property Injection does not work out-of-the-box, you need to set up class you want to use property injection in, so

```
builder.RegisterType<MyGlobalService>().As<IGlobalService>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
```

should do the trick. Or you could do this manually using `OnActivating` lifetime event.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks